# what is the difference between being neither even nor odd and being none of these

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

$f(x)$ is an odd function and $g(x)$ is neither even nor odd,Then $f(x)
+ g(x)$

(a). Even

(b) Odd

(c)Nither even nor odd

(d)None of these.

$\boldsymbol{My}$$\boldsymbol{Approach}$$\Longrightarrow$I know
(a) and(b) incorrect.

But i dont know which one is correct between (c) and (d).What is the
difference between (c) and (d).??

And What is the key to recognize ???

Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 1$. Then $f\;$is even.

First, let $g(x) = x-1$. Then $g\;$is neither even nor odd, but $f+g\;$is odd.

Next, let $g(x) = x+1$. Then $g\;$is neither even nor odd, and $f+g\;$is also neither even nor odd.

The first example disqualifies $(c)$, and the second example disqualifies $(a)\;$and $(b)$.

Hence, "none of these" is correct.